# Create and send an e-mail with a scheduled time in outlook with python

Tags: python, win32com

I would like to create and send an e-mail with a scheduled time (with delay delivery in the options tab) in outlook with python.
The script below simply sends an email without a delivery time option:

```
import win32com.client as win32 
def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):
 outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
 mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
 mail.To = recipient
 mail.Subject = subject
 mail.HtmlBody = text
 mail.send
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.deferreddeliverytime

Answer (score 2):

I added the line below, as an example, it worked.

```
mail.DeferredDeliveryTime = datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 17, 29, 25, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```